# Arxiv undefined control sequence. \XKV@tempa ->\field

Tags: packages, arxiv

I would love to upload my document to ArXiv, but ArXiv cannot process my file:

```
Package biblatex Warning: 
File 'myfile.bbl' created by wrong version.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XKV@tempa ->\field 

l.1324 \end
{document}
? 
! Emergency stop.
\XKV@tempa ->\field
```

I am using the following packages:

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{authblk}
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=numeric-comp,citestyle=numeric-comp,firstinits=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false}{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

I am using TeXShop 3.23 on mac and I don't get those errors. 
I guess I have a differnent `.sty`? I have the feeling that `biblatex` is causing the problems, since I could upload without this packages and references.
Does anyone know what I could do?

Thanks

Comment: How did you upload the bibliography?